# How to append a variable to a .mat file?

Tags: matlab, variables, save

If I already have a `.mat` file with the variables `x` and `y`, is there a way to use the `save` command to add another variable `z` to the `.mat` file without having to explicitly state the variables `x` and `y` in the save command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [`save()` function documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/save.html), there is a form of the save command that might help:

```
save(filename, ..., '-append')
```

The help for this form says:

> `save(filename, ..., '-append')` adds new variables to an existing file. You can specify the '-append' option with additional inputs such as variables, '-struct' , format, or version.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual page](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/save.html):

> ```
> save(filename)
> save(filename, variables)
> save(filename, '-struct', structName, fieldNames)
> save(filename, ..., '-append')
> save(filename, ..., format)
> save(filename, ..., version)
> save filename ...
> ```
>
> ...
>
> `save(filename, ..., '-append')` adds new variables to an existing file. You can specify the `'-append'` option with additional inputs
>   such as variables, `'-struct'` , format, or version.